# Could I use yum to install package on redhat without root?

Tags: server, redhat, yum

I recently rent a server for web-app testing purpose. Below is my server info, I assume it's Redhat linux. (I have used Ubuntu for a while).

> ```
> Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) 
> [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
> ```

When I wanted to install tmux on the server, I was thinking about using YUM for ease (not compile myself). When I type yum in terminal, nothing come out.

```
nl0391 [~]$ which yum
nl0391 [~]$
```

There is no rpm as well.

I supposed there is no yum installed. So I was thinking about installing yum myself from source. I got sources of yum and found I need gettext for installing yum. So I compiled gettext on my home successfully and continued to compile yum.

First I used `./configure --configure=~/.usr/local` to point to my home dir which I have permission to write.

Then `make` and `make install`.

During `make install`, there's some problem with `/etc/yum.config`. It was also the permission issue so I change the `MakeFile` to let config in my `~/ect/yum.config`. This helped to successfully compile yum and finish installation.

I can successfully run command `yum` or `man yum`. I believe the installation is right.

But when I ran `yum install tmux` or `yum info` (let yum do something), the errors kept going out like below:

```
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wxx920521/.usr/local/bin/yum", line 31, in <module>
    yummain.main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/wxx920521/.usr/local/src/yum-2.0.7/yummain.py", line 163, in main
    (log, errorlog, filelog, conf, cmds) = parseCmdArgs(args)
  File "/home/wxx920521/.usr/local/src/yum-2.0.7/yummain.py", line 75,       in parseCmdArgs
    conf=yumconf(configfile=yumconffile)
  File "/home/wxx920521/.usr/local/src/yum-2.0.7/config.py", line 155,     in __init__
    self.yumvar['releasever'] = self._getsysver()
  File "/home/wxx920521/.usr/local/src/yum-2.0.7/config.py", line 285, in _getsysver
    idx = ts.dbMatch('provides', self.distroverpkg)
_rpm.error: rpmdb open failed.
```

I even changed the python files of YUM to fix the `yum.conf` file path issues, but for rpmdb issue I just realized manually resolving this path might be nightmare and impossible.

So I am wondering if I can use YUM on the root for which I don't have root permission? I can directly compile tmux in my home. Is it worthwhile to devote time compiling yum which potentially can't use if no root? Since I know on ubuntu `apt-get install` needs sudo before any usage?

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like RHEL6, but it seems almost impossible for RHEL6 to have been installed without yum. This is suspicious enough that I would recommend not renting this server and taking your money elsewhere.

Comment: What is suspicious enough? Do you mean RHEL6 should come with YUM?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format inline code and paragraphs so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: You can always add the `yum` command to the sudoers file and set it to run as root without asking for password.

Comment: @Yaron Actually, it's not using password to run Yum. I believe this server doesn't come with Yum. The problem is whether is worthwhile to compile yum myself, or it's simpler to compile any software directly without using Yum. It's my first time using RHEL, just heard Yum is like apt-get in ubuntu

Comment: @XXWang are you certain about the release? have you tried running it with `sudo`?

Comment: @Yaron I got this server from Godaddy, I am suspecting do I have the root privilege to switch root. I even find I can't access sudo or su wxx920521@a2plcpnl0391 [~]$ sudo
-bash: sudo: command not found
wxx920521@a2plcpnl0391 [~]$ su
-bash: su: command not found
I am not 100% with the distributor, the python starting output said it's redhat. Also /proc/version said it's redhat;  [~]$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Feb 10 08:57:30 EST 2016